# How to install latest Android SDK tool in Mac

Tags: android

I am trying to setup Android SDK tool for Genymotion. I downloaded the standalone SDK tool but I am not sure how to install it. The download folder screenshot

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: that doesn't look like Android SDK

Answer (score 0):

You can download and update  sdk from Android studio 
Easily click on sdk update icon and open sdk location and 
 Download which you have required build tools in middle tab.

Check check box Show all details 
And show all details.

Comment: I use VS code for development. Hence only want SDK to be installed on my machine.

Comment: So you can download from android developer side and put this sdk on your Library folder and access from this location.

Comment: And sdk is not install in our system this is only put in Library or our home folder